# Extracting hidden Info from R Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe looks like below:

```
person    year    Office        Job      rank
Harry     2002    Los Angeles   CEO       0
Harry     2006    Boston        CEO       0
Harry     2006    Los Angeles   Advisor   1
Harry     2006    Chicago       Chairman  2

Peter     2001    New York      Director  0
Peter     2001    Chicago       CFO       1
Peter     2001    Chicago       COO       2
Peter     2002    Chicago       CEO       0

Lily      2005    Springfield   CEO       0
Lily      2007    New York      CFO       0
Lily      2008    Boston        COO       0
Lily      2011    Chicago       Advisor   0
Lily      2011    New York      board     1
 
Sam       2006    Chicago       COO       0
Sam       2007    Chicago       CFO       0
Sam       2007    Chicago       CEO       1
Sam       2010    New York      Advisor   0
```

I want to know at a person level, who has at least one of the following two patterns:

1. in a previous available year, an office has rank 0 and in the next available year, the office still exist but rank is no longer and should be bigger than 0 (job does not matter). For example, Los Angeles for Harry.
2. in a next available year, an office has rank 0 and in the previous available year, the office still exist but rank is is no longer and should be bigger than 0 (For example, Chicago for Peter).

Note that New York for Lily does not have either of the above situation as 2007 is not the previous available year for Lily (2008 is).

Note that an office can exist multiple times in a year (differ in jobs). Chicago for Sam shows one such case. Note that Chicago for Sam also does not count as although Chicago has rank 1 in 2007 and rank 0 in previous available year, Chicago also has rank 0 in 2007.

Thus, the output should look like:

```
person    yes/no
Harry     1
Peter     1
Lily      0
Sam       0
```

Comment: What is an "available year"? I'm pretty confused about the logic you are using. For example, you say "2007 is not the previous available year for Lily (2008 is)" but the data only has rows for 2007 and 2011 for New York for Lily.

Comment: Thanks for asking! The basic unit is person, not person/location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think this will work. You want to:

1. Figure out if any job in a person-year-office are rank 0
2. For each person-office, check the two cases you're interested in (current row has a rank 0, and either the previous or the next does not have a rank 0. This is easier to do if you expand the dataframe to include all combinations for each person-year for each office.
3. For each person, check if any row matches either case you specified and fill the missing values.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- read_table(
"person    year    Office        Job      rank
Harry     2002    Los Angeles   CEO       0
Harry     2006    Boston        CEO       0
Harry     2006    Los Angeles   Advisor   1
Harry     2006    Chicago       Chairman  2
Peter     2001    New York      Director  0
Peter     2001    Chicago       CFO       1
Peter     2001    Chicago       COO       2
Peter     2002    Chicago       CEO       0
Lily      2005    Springfield   CEO       0
Lily      2007    New York      CFO       0
Lily      2008    Boston        COO       0
Lily      2011    Chicago       Advisor   0
Lily      2011    New York      board     1
Sam       2006    Chicago       COO       0
Sam       2007    Chicago       CFO       0
Sam       2007    Chicago       CEO       1
Sam       2010    New York      Advisor   0
"
)
df %>%
  group_by(person, year, Office) %>%
  summarise(any_rank_0 = any(rank == 0)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  complete(nesting(person, year), Office) %>%
  arrange(person, Office, year) %>%
  group_by(person, Office) %>%
  mutate(
    case_1 = any_rank_0 & !lead(any_rank_0), #current 0, next not 0
    case_2 = any_rank_0 & !lag(any_rank_0) #current 0, previous not 0
  ) %>%
  group_by(person) %>%
  summarise(result = replace_na(any(case_1) | any(case_2), FALSE))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   person result
#>   <chr>  <lgl> 
#> 1 Harry  TRUE  
#> 2 Lily   FALSE 
#> 3 Peter  TRUE  
#> 4 Sam    FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>